# Options for providing a dynamic filter

Tags: c#, sql, search, webforms

I am currently working on a project that requires a dynamic filter option.  This would be a combobox, used to determine the filter type, and a textbox, used to get the search key.  What I am wanting to do is make this as dynamic as possible.  I don't want to have to come back into the source code and change it if the customer decides they want a new one on the fly.

The data is currently spread across two databases, I have no say in this.  This has discouraged the use of Entity Framework and Dynamic LINQ.  The current idea I have is to bind the combobox to "filters" that are stored in the database with the T-SQL to execute to get the results and use sp_executesql to get them back, which can be seen [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c2cd6/1).

I would like some other recommendations on how I can accomplish this.  I feel there should be an elegant way think can be done in C#, but I can't think of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a DropDownList (named here yourDdl) and you want to fill it with data coming from a DB I suggest you to do something like this:

```
yourDdl.DataSource = getListSelection("AtecoYear = 2004", true);
yourDdl.DataTextField = "ComboText";
yourDdl.DataValueField = "ComboID";
yourDdl.DataBind();
```

The method getListSelection (the best way would be to put it in a proper class) connects to your DB, extracts the data and put it into a DataTable:

```
public DataTable getListSelection(string filter_status)
{
    DataTable dt;
    string cmdText = "select ExampleID as ComboID, ExampleName as ComboText from ExampleTable";

    SqlConnection objIdbConnection = new SqlConnection(yourConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = cmdText;
    cmd.Connection = objIdbConnection;
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 30; // seconds
    cmd.Connection.Open();

    IDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter((SqlCommand)cmd);
    DataSet myDataTable = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(myDataTable);
    objIdbConnection.Close();

return myDataTable.Tables[0];
```

}

Comment: Sorry, I maybe wrong, but it seems you are showing me HOW to put data into the combobox.  This isn't an issue, what is the issue is having my filters being as dynamic as possible so I don't have to maintain my source code to add a new filter in.

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood your question. Looking at the fiddle, it seems to me you're almost done with your job. You probably have just to replace the CommandText with the execution of your SP.